# How to set delay for multiple ajax calls and bind a stop button to them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a small app to make multiple ajax calls to the server. Each call should be made in sequence and the interval is 1 sec. And if the stop button is clicked, all remaining calls should be aborted. I've tried code like below but couldn't make it to work. The time interval doesn't work, and I've no idea where I should bind the stop button.

```
<button id="startbtn">Start!</button>
<button id="stoptbn">Stop!</button>

<script>

function makeajax(num) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/testurl",
    data: {
       num: num
    },
    complete: function (result) {
        console.log(num);
        setTimeout(makeajax, 1000);
    } } )
};
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#startbtn").click(function () {
      var data_array = [1, 2, 3];
      for (var i=0; i < data_array.length; i++) {
          makeajax(data_array[i]);
      };
</script>
```

Comment: Don't make multiple requests in very quick succession. Collate the data and make a single request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use a for loop statement:

```
<button id="startbtn">Start!</button>
<button id="stoptbn">Stop!</button>

<script>
var xhrs = [];
function makeajax(arr) {
  if (arr !== null && arr.length > 0){
    var num = arr.shift();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrs.push(xhr);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/testurl",
        xhr : function(){
           return xhr;
        },
        data: {
           num: num
        },
        complete: function (result) {
           if (!(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0)) {
             console.log(num);
             setTimeout(() => makeajax(arr), 1000);
           }
        }
    });
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#startbtn").click(function () {
      var data_array = [1, 2, 3];
      makeajax(data_array);
   });
   $("#stopbtn").click(function () {
      xhrs.forEach(xhr => xhr.abort());
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, the start part works. But stop button doesn't work as expected. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).abort is not a function

Comment: sorry !!! I have "jQuerized" the xhr object and we should not do this. Answer updated by the way.

Comment: No alert or exception now. But couln't be stopped either.

Comment: Look at this answer : stackoverflow.com/a/446626 , answer updated.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, all the requests are returned as "failed" because the remote server is mis-configured, while actually the post is success. Does that matter?

Comment: According to the MDN, the readyState and the status code are set to 4 and 0 respectively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

One way is this. If you want to stop calling the next ajax query, but still handle the one that was in progress.

```
var callNr = 0;
var stopId;
var data_array = [1, 2, 3];
var isStopped;
function makeajax() {
  if (!data_array.length || isStopped) { alert('no more queries'); return;}
  num = data_array.shift();
  callNr++;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/testurl",
    data: {
       num: num
    },
    complete: function (result) {
        console.log(num);
        if (!isStopped) {
            stopId = setTimeout(makeajax, 1000);
        }
        $("#response").text('Response nr:' + callNr);
    } } );
};
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#startbtn").click(function () {
      isStopped = false;
      makeajax();
   });
   $("#stoptbn").click(function() {
       clearTimeout(stopId);
       isStopped = true;
       console.log('stopped');
   });
});

<button id="startbtn">Start!</button>
<button id="stoptbn">Stop!</button>
<button id="response">No response yet</button>
```

[JsFiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/axz3mhag/6/embed/)

Comment: Works as expected. But sorry only one answer can be adopted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

chcek this,

```
   function makeajax(num) {
     jqXHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/testurl",
        async : false,
        data: {
           num: num
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //Do anything you want
        },
        timeout: 3000
    };

    $("#abortAjax").click(function() { // Id of the button you want to bind 
        $(jqXHR).abort();
    });

    }
```